# How to specify auto commit to false explicitly in pandas

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

In a small program, I'm using the Pandas to_sql method to push data to the database. But in my scenario, I need to set auto-commit to false, but Pandas commits nonetheless. Is there a workaround for this?

```
# Example code
df = pd.read_csv(file)

# In here i need to turn auto commit off
with conn.connect() as c:
    df.to_sql('table_name', c)

    # Some critical workload
    # updating another table
    # Then commit after updating the table
    c.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQLAlchemy 2.0, `with engine.connect() as c:` and `with engine.begin() as c:` normally differ in that the former *will not* automatically commit when the context manager exits, while the latter *will* automatically commit (unless an error occurs). So,

```py
engine.echo = True
with engine.connect() as c:
    c.exec_driver_sql("INSERT INTO table_name (id) VALUES (1)")
print(">>> Done.")
```

results in a rollback

```
… INSERT INTO table_name (id) VALUES (1)
… [raw sql] ()
… ROLLBACK
>>> Done.
```

However, `to_sql()` does automatically commit

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,), (2,)], columns=["id"])
engine.echo = True
with engine.connect() as c:
    df.to_sql("table_name", c, if_exists="append", index=False)
print(">>> Done.")
```

```
… INSERT INTO table_name (id) VALUES (?)
… [generated in 0.00087s] [(1,), (2,)]
… COMMIT
>>> Done.
```

and the commit happens immediately after the `.to_sql()` completes, as shown by adding a breakpoint within the context manager

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,), (2,)], columns=["id"])
engine.echo = True
with engine.connect() as c:
    df.to_sql("table_name", c, if_exists="append", index=False)
    breakpoint()
    print("Exiting context manager.")
print(">>> Done.")
```

```
2023-06-28 07:09:13,887 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO table_name (id) VALUES (?)
2023-06-28 07:09:13,887 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00066s] [(1,), (2,)]
2023-06-28 07:09:13,912 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
> /home/gord/PycharmProjects/sqlalchemy_demo/so76566226.py(14)<module>()
-> print("Exiting context manager.")
(Pdb)
```

But, `.to_sql()` only seems to immediately automatically commit if a transaction is not active when it is invoked, so if we begin the transaction ourselves then the `.to_sql()` won't be committed until we commit the transaction ourselves

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,), (2,)], columns=["id"])
engine.echo = True
with engine.connect() as c, c.begin():
    df.to_sql("table_name", c, if_exists="append", index=False)
    breakpoint()
    c.commit()
print(">>> Done.")
```

```
2023-06-28 07:15:57,699 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO table_name (id) VALUES (?)
2023-06-28 07:15:57,699 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00052s] [(1,), (2,)]
> /home/gord/PycharmProjects/sqlalchemy_demo/so76566226.py(14)<module>()
-> c.commit()
(Pdb) next
2023-06-28 07:16:13,131 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
> /home/gord/PycharmProjects/sqlalchemy_demo/so76566226.py(15)<module>()
-> print(">>> Done.")
(Pdb)
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the auto-commit feature and manually control the transaction, you can use the `if_exists='append'` option in the `to_sql`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def disable_auto_commit(connection, _):
    connection.connection.autocommit = False


engine = create_engine('your_database_connection_string')


with engine.connect() as connection:
    df.to_sql('table_name', connection, if_exists='append', method=disable_auto_commit)

    
    connection.execute('COMMIT')
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is using `sqlachemy`. You can try below code -

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 

conn_engine = create_engine("db_connection_String", echo=False)

with conn_engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execution_options(autocommit = False)
    df.to_sql('table_name', conn)
```